# Thymeleaf Form passing null object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm newish to Spring Web and Thymeleaf and I'm trying to make a form which passes a Todo object to a controller, which saves that object to a database. The form accepts inputs, but the actual object passed to the post method has all null and default values. I've found similar issues on stack overflow, but none of the solutions seem to apply. Am I missing something?

TodoController.java:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/todos")
public class TodoController {
    @Autowired
    TodoRepository todoRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public String getAllTodos(Model model, @ModelAttribute Todo todo) {
        List<Todo> todos = todoRepository.findAll();

        model.addAttribute("todos", todos);
        model.addAttribute("todo", new Todo());
        return "test";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/post")
    public String addUser(Model model, @ModelAttribute("todo") Todo todo) {
        System.out.println("POST!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! : " + todo.toString());
        todoRepository.save(todo);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

Form element from test.html:

```html
<form method="post" th:action="@{/todos/post}" th:object="${todo}">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" required type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
    <label for="description">Description</label>
    <input id="description" placeholder="Enter Description" required type="text" th:field="*{description}"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Create Todo">
</form>
```

Todo.java:

```java
public record Todo(@Id Long id, Long userId, String name, String description, boolean completed) {
    public Todo() {
        this(null, null, "","", false);
    }
}
```

When I enter an object with values for name and description, the terminal prints out an object with only null and default values (empty strings):

```
POST!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! : Todo[id=null, userId=null, name=, description=, completed=false]
```

And successfully saves that object to the database:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

The problem seems to be either the form, the connection between the form and the endpoint, or some complication of using records. Beyond that I'm stuck.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Haven't tried this but since Records are supposed to be immutable, this shouldn't work. Try with normal pojo class instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Chetan Ahetao got it. Records are immutable. Had to use a regular class with Entity annotations.